# Using windows dll from python 3.11 and ctypes gives exception: access violation reading 0x00000

Tags: python-3.x, windows, ctypes, dllexport

I'm facing following situation:

a third party Windows DLL (64bit on my current system) with following signature:

```
EXPORTS WORD  CALLBACK  Ixud_DriverInit(WORD *wTotalBoards);
EXPORTS WORD  CALLBACK  Ixud_DriverClose(void);
```

found return a number of found devices
return value is return code 0 == success

and I try to use it with:

```
from ctypes import *
from ctypes.wintypes import WORD, DWORD
import platform

bits, system = platform.architecture()
if system.startswith('Windows'):
    if bits.startswith('64'):
        shared_lib_path = "./DLL/x64/my.dll"
    else:
        shared_lib_path = "./DLL/x86/my.dll"
    
# handling of the others
    
instance = CDLL(shared_lib_path)

close = instance.Ixud_DriverClose
close.restype = WORD
ret = close() # works fine I get success here

found = WORD(0)
init = instance.Ixud_DriverInit
init.argtypes = [POINTER(WORD)]
init.restype = WORD
retcode = init(byref(found))
return retcode, found.value
```

Line: `retcode = init(byref(found))` fails with:

`OSError('exception: access violation reading 0x000000000000003C')`

Not sure what I have missed.

Comment: What does the *C* function do? Pleas post its code, as the problem doesn't seem to be here. also, correctly indent your code. Based on the error I guess you're on *064bit*.

Comment: Sadly I have no access to source of the dll it's a third party. yes I'm testing on 64bit system. Init should load drive and return number of found hardware.

Comment: Any documentation on the function and arguments? What's the pointer for?

Comment: The pointer will return the number of found and initialized devices. No need of sending a specific value to the dll

Comment: Then what's the return value for?

Comment: It returns the error code. For code  close() return is success. So general wrapping of dll seems to work.

Comment: Is the driver installed and working properly? Is the card plugged in? Can you use it from other software?

Comment: Yes test tool delivered with the hardware works fine. So I assume no problem with installed drivers

Comment: You haven't missed anything.  Code as shown works (with a simple implementation like `typedef unsigned short WORD; WORD Ixud_DriverInit(WORD* found) { *found = 2; return 1; }` (at least if you change the `return` to a `print()` since the code doesn't define a function).  Show the *exact* C header file definitions of the functions and typedefs.

Comment: I updated question with content from header file I found in an example instead of what they have written in the docs

Comment: What’s the precise #define/typedef for WORD and CALLBACK?

Comment: It uses windows.h as defined here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types?redirectedfrom=MSDN